# Restricting subdomains using regex in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'd like to know how to limit(not rate limiting) subdomains effectively. Here's my example where the redirecting of invalid subdomains is handled by an if statement with regex matching.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.com *.domain.com;
  set $host_red 0;
  if ($host !~ (sub1|sub2\.*\.nm|newsub[0-9]*\.nm)\.domain.com) {
    set $host 1;
  }
  if ($host) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
  }
  ...
}
```

One approach would be to create another server block with this regex and remove `*.domain.com` from the current server block. But this would mean duplicating a lot of common configs across these two server blocks. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you will duplicate content if the only thing you intend to do is redirecting between domains. This is also a good idea to avoid ifs when you can because it brings a performance penalty.

But the biggest thing going is : it's a very bad idea to answer the same thing for more than one domain name as search engines will penalize you for content duplication. The following configuration should be what you are looking for :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    ...
}
```

It will answer requests for `www.domain.com` and redirect all the other domains to it with the right redirection code for SEO.

Comment: Actually I was working on refactoring some pre-existing nginx configs and now I've begun to question the sanity of those existing configs. I'd like to know if the config at [http://p.ngx.cc/32](http://p.ngx.cc/32) makes sense as both www.domain.com and secure.domain.com are now pointing to the same php server.

Comment: @EmmanuelLivingstone It depends on the rest of the config. But if you serve the same content from multiple domains, it's content duplication too.

Comment: sub1.domain.com, sub2.qa.domain.com are all internal dns addresses that aren't publicly available. They are usually used to partition the work. So I guess this wouldn't amount to content duplication.